# Kafka producers/brokers not using specified IP

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

So I have a cluster of 6 machines. These machines have 2 IP address (a public and a private). The private IPs are using a high speed network (1 GBps) and the public are using a slower network (120 MBps).

While configuring my kafka/zookeeper cluster, I had set the private IP as the brokers's ip. Now my configuration is fine as I can see output saying that all my brokers are connected on the correct IP

```
 INFO Connecting to zookeeper on 10.11.10.2:2181,10.11.10.3:2181,10.11.10.4:2181,10.11.10.5:2181,10.11.10.6:2181,10.11.10.7:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Now when I was testing the producer's performance, I could get a throughput more than 120 MBps.

```
bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic highthr2 --num-records 10000 --record-size 100000 --throughput 10000 --producer-props acks=-1 bootstrap.servers=10.11.10.2:9092,10.11.10.3:9092,10.11.10.4:9092,10.11.10.5:9092,10.11.10.6:9092,10.11.10.7:9092
```

When I used nload, to check how much data is going through each interface, I found that data was coming in and going out through the public IP interface (slower network interface). I rechecked the zookeeper and kafka logs, but they both say that my brokers are on the private IP.

Any ideas on what is the issue or what do I need to change?

Comment: Did you set 'advertised.listeners'? Besides, which IP address is mapped to the host name?

Comment: Thanks, I had not set 'advertised.listeners'. After setting it, I can see the traffic on the right interface.  But I am still not able to saturate the network, my producer is able to send 253.01 MBps, i.e. 2 Gbps instead of 10 Gbps. Any ideas on what I can do to saturate the network?

Comment: Have multiple producers to delivery messages simultaneously. Besides, try to tune batch size, partition number and linger.ms for further performance gains.

Comment: Don't forget to count the replication traffic. A publish rate of 2Gbps ingress is really 6 Gbps of total network bandwidth if you have a replication factor of 3. It's 8Gbps if you have an active consumer so that's getting close the maximum usable bandwidth on a 10 gigE link.